# dart pub test... can you exclude files / directories?

Tags: testing, dart, transformer-model

dart/pub v1.10

I have a test/e2e folder that has webdriver.dart tests.  'pub run test' is trying to run the dart files in e2e.

```
pubspec.yaml
dev_dependencies:
    test: '>=0.12.1 <0.13.0'
```

I've been running the webdriver.dart test as

```
dart test/e2e/some_test.dart
```

Was hoping pub/test implemented a transformer... so I just just exclude it in pubspec.yaml. No joy.  Can I build a transformer for test?

Ideas? (besides moving the directory out from under test :-))

**update**
looks like my options are:

1. pub run test test/unit (specify the directory)
2. move the e2e folder out of 'test'

Answer (score 1):

You can filter tests using the `--name=xxx` (where xxx can be a regular expression) or the `--plain-name=xxx` (just substring comparsion) parameters to filter tests. There is an open issue to add tags as well but I don't know if this is actually planned.

I don't know what you expect a transformer to do. If you use includes/excludes to the transformer configuration this specifies only which files are processed by the transformer but not which files are executed.

Comment: In my scenario $exclude would be used to tell the test runner not to execute e2e tests by default.  Guess I can accomplish this my specifying the directory 'pub run test test/unit' or by moving e2e out of the test folder.